# Windows 10 laptop shuts down instead of sleep

Tags: laptop, sleep, shutdown

For the past few days, my Acer laptop keeps shutting down whenever I close the lid or when I try to put it to sleep. When I choose "sleep" and I close the lid, and when I open it again, it takes a long time to turn on and the acer logo appears and it reboots. When I open my browser, it says "system did not shut down properly" or something like that. I'm not sure if my computer is crashing every time I close the lid or not. I set "choose what close the lid does" and "choose what the power buttons do" in the power options correctly but it still doesn't work. I also updated the BIOS for my laptop. I've seen some people say that the laptop shutting down problem is sometimes because of the Intel Management Engine Interface but my laptop doesn't even have the Intel section in device manager. Please help me fix my laptop from shutting down when I press the sleep mode and also shutting down whenever I close the lid.

Answer (score 0):

check your bios settings for power management, I think there should be a tab in there somewhere for power management, Access BIOS at boot up by pressing F12 sometimes F3. Check your power management settings in windows itself I even want to say it could be a bad battery.

Comment: Could also be your enabled Hybrid Sleep (or it was enabled by default on your PC), which, as the name implies, is a hybrid between regular Sleep (RAM content isn't flushed; power to the chipset is maintained) and Hibernation (RAM content is copied to disk; power to the chipset is cut off), and something goes wrong during the copying-to-disk phase. Can you tell us more about your PC (how much RAM, CPU, free space, SSD vs HDD, size of the hibernation file, etc...)?

Comment: Yes, my Hybrid Sleep is enabled. Would that make a difference? I have 26 GB free space, my laptop uses SSD, I have 8 GB of RAM (6 GB still usable), and I don't know how to find the size of the hibernation file.

Comment: How would I know if it is the battery problem? And what do I do in the power management setting in bios?